# Autofac XML configuration - Define instance properties

Tags: c#, xml, properties, instance, autofac

I want to define instance properties by using the autofac XML configuration.

Example:

```
public interface ITest {} // no properties, just plain interface
public class ConcreteTest : ITest 
{ 
    public string SomeText {get; set;} 
}
```

Configuration:

```
<!-- language: xml -->
<component
   type="Namespace.ConcreteTest"
   service="Namespace.ITest">
   <properties>
      <property name="SomeText" value="Text to be set on concrete instance" />
   </properties>
</component>
```

This will work fine if ITest has "SomeText" property which is not my case.
Is this possible with autofac?
Can I tell autofac to search in type properties instead of service?